# Converting string array to hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, logic

I have the following response

```
T2269|175@@2a1d2d89aa96ddd6|45464047
```

By using the **split("\\|")** i have converted into string array object. The meaning for the each field is as follows:

```
T2269                  id
175@@2a1d2d89aa96ddd6  cid
45464047               refno
```

No i have to convert it into HashMap object . Is their any solution for the above..

**The above response is given for example. In real, the length of the string array object is 36.**

Comment: What would be the keys and the values in your map? Do you mean a map with three entries (id = T2269, cid = 175..., refno = 4546...) ? Or a map where the values are objects with three fields (id, cid, refno)? In that case what would be the key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
final String[] fields = input.split("\\|");
final Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
int i = 0;
for (String key : new String[] {"id", "cid", "refno"})
  m.put(key, fields[i++]);
```

Comment: now how to get some fields[i] ??

Answer (score 11):

You have to loop and add the results one by one.
Declare an array with the keys, something like:

```
static String[] keys = new String[]{"id", "cid", "refno", ...};
```

and then

```
String[] s = text.split("\\|");
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
  map.put(keys[i], s[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key should be unique, so obviously using the ID as a key would make perfect sense, and the value you can store as an array/list containing the id,cid,refno, or you can create an object containing thos fields and store it.